# Explicit solution to transport equation possible?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have the transport equation with time variable $t$ and space variable $x=(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb R^2$. We then consider the transport equation

$$\partial_t f(t,x) + (x_2 \partial_{x_1}-x_1\partial_{x_2}) f(t,x)=0,\quad f(0,x)=f_0(x).$$

I am wondering if one can find an explicit solution to this equation?

Comment: Are you familiar with the method of characteristics?

Comment: @K.defaoite no, do you think you could explain it?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics).

Comment: Where did you encounter this equation? Why is it important to you? Answer these questions and I'll be happy to post an answer.